# Dropdown menu not showing in bootstrap after slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Dropdown menu in Bootstrap doesn't appear after slideToggle.

First time this was showing in large screen (full size)
when i resize browser into small view(mobile screen) then dropdown menu showing into slidetoggle and proper working,
after that i again resize screen in large screen then it was hide.
and when i refresh the page then it is showing.
can anyone have idea about it.

```
<div class="top-nav cl-effect-5">
<span class="menu-icon"><img src="images/menu-icon.png" alt=""/></span> 
        <ul class="nav1">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active"><span data-hover="Home">Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> <span data-hover="About">About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html"> <span data-hover="Services">Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html"> <span data-hover="News">News</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> <span data-hover="Contact">Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
<!-- script-for-menu -->
    <script>
    $("span.menu-icon").click(function () {
    $("ul.nav1").slideToggle(300, function () {
    // Animation complete.
     });
     });
    </script>
    <!-- /script-for-menu -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have done what you are looking for. This may help you. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lghuempp

```js
 $("span.menu-icon").click(function () {
     if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
         $("ul.nav1").slideToggle();
         $("ul.nav1").addClass('open');
     } else {
         $("ul.nav1").removeClass('open');
     }
 });

 $(window).resize(function () {
     if ($(window).width() > 767) {
         if ($("ul.nav1").hasClass('open')) {
             $("ul.nav1").removeClass('open');
             $("ul.nav1").css("display", "none");
         } else {
             $("ul.nav1").css("display", "block");
         }
     } else{
         if ($('ul.nav1').is(':visible')) {
       $("ul.nav1").css("display", "none");
         }
     }
 });
```

```css
.nav1 {
    display:block;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .nav1 {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-nav cl-effect-5">
<span class="menu-icon">Menu icon</span> 
    <ul class="nav1">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active"><span data-hover="Home">Home</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html"> <span data-hover="About">About</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html"> <span data-hover="Services">Services</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="news.html"> <span data-hover="News">News</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html"> <span data-hover="Contact">Contact</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'navbar-collapse'

```
<span class="menu-icon navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav1">
<ul class="nav1 navbar-collapse collapse">
```